# module 'ibis.impala' has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python, impala, ibis

I have installed Python3.5 and ibis-framework 0.10.0. I want to operate Pandas data to impala database directly. But i meet the following error. Would you help me to solve it? The command line as following:

```
import ibis
conn = ibis.impala.connect(host='192.168.1.14', port=21050)
```

The error message as following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
conn = ibis.impala.connect(host='192.168.1.14', port=21050)
AttributeError: module 'ibis.impala' has no attribute 'connect'
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you need to do this `pip install ibis-framework[impala]`, see the link here  [ibis doc](http://docs.ibis-project.org/getting-started.html#)

Answer (score 0):

it seems to have been moved in the `ibis.impala.api` submodule also if you would have to install `hdfs` otherwise it seems to fail